# How do I use the modulo operators in Socrata SoQL?

Tags: socrata, soda

https://dev.socrata.com/docs/datatypes/number.html#, says that % and ^ can be used to get the modulo of one number divided by another number.  I cannot get them to work and cannot find examples.

When I try ^ I appear to get exponentiation. Example:

http://data.cityofchicago.org/resource/pubx-yq2d.json?$select=streetnumberto,streetnumberfrom,(streetnumberto-streetnumberfrom)^100%20as%20address_length_in_blocks

When I try % itself, I get a "malformed" error, not so surprisingly.  When I try the %25 code for %, I still get a "malformed" error but one that seems to suggest that it correctly inserted the % but does not know what it means.  (I am restricted from posting more than two links but just replace the ^ above with % and %25.)

Can anyone help me get this working?

By the way, at the risk of mixing topics, I would ideally like to use an int or round sort of function but they do not seem to exist in SoQL so I was trying to back into getting the integer portion of dividing by 100.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Great question. I just tried it myself and I'm getting a malformed exception too, and it's definitely getting through to the query optimizer:

https://data.cityofchicago.org/resource/erhc-fkv9.json?totalfees=4160%20%25%2010.0

Note I'm using the SODA 2.1 version of that API, which I recommend you migrate to:

https://dev.socrata.com/foundry/#/data.cityofchicago.org/erhc-fkv9

I'll check with our engineering team and see what might be going on. I'll pass on the feature request for `round`, `ceil`, `floor`, etc as well.